# Pagination not working in when result coming from ajax

Tags: javascript, html, css, pagination

I am trying to pagination without jquery and in pure javascript.
Pagination javascript working fine in normal, but when I adding ajax and getting from the result, that time not working pagination.
I am taking reference link is 
https://coderanch.com/t/597555/frameworks/Countdown-timer-Pagination-Javascript
My ajax script is

```js
function showResult(elem) {
  var data_search = elem;
  var dataarray = {
    "value": data_search
  };
  var data = JSON.stringify(dataarray);

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("POST", "search_ajax.php", true);
  request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
      var data1 = request.responseText;
      document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = data1;
    }
  }
  request.send(data);
}
```

Kindly suggest a solution, thanks in advance